# Remote desktop via ad hoc network, cannot reach IP

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-address

I am trying to access a windows XP desktop machine, using the microsoft remote desktop client running on a mac laptop, over an ad hoc wifi connection set up on the XP machine. The XP machine is also on a local ethernet network with internet access, but I am not sharing the internet connection over the ad hoc wifi network.

I can connect the mac laptop to the ad hoc network. However, when I then take the IP address for the desktop's wireless device (external USB, not an internal card) as given by ipconfig on the XP machine, and try to connect to that IP in the remote desktop client on the laptop, it cannot connect. Pinging the IP from the laptop also fails.

Is there a different IP address that I should be using, that I can determine somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your XP machine now has 2 network interfaces.  I suspect you are trying to connect to the IP address of the wired network card.  You need to use the IP address of the wireless card.

Changes are that the wireless card has not been assigned an IP address automatically on the XP box and so you may have to set that yourself.

If this does not solve the problem please add the i{p,f}config output of both mac and windows machines to your question.